# Web order/request pool

Tags: windows, linux, web-apps, web-development, html

I'm looking for some kind of web software that runs on browsers that allows me to do some kind of request/order pool. It doesn't need to fit all my needs, but if gives me a starting point, it would be really useful.

Here's what I personally want to accomplish (not necessarily the software must do all of this):

- I want to each of my costumers to have an account on this system.

  - The accounts must be secured by some kind of authentication.
- There must be some kind of way for me to open a new order pool.

  - Ideally an admin account of some sort.
  - These pools would be open when the week starts, and closed when the week ends.
- When clients log in, they see the open pools, and they may choose to place an order on that pool.
- The pool's content would be something like: 10 product X, 25 product Y, 50 product Z, 5 product W.
- Clients then should be able to see and place an order on that pool.
- Clients may see the total amount of orders within this pool made by other clients, but may not see who placed them.

The idea here is to allow clients to see approximately how much products will be produced this week, and how's the demand. Sometimes we can reach the demand, sometimes we over produce, sometimes some clients doesn't get the full order. That's up to me how I'm going to tell that to the clients.

- The webapp could run on any of the popular server/database available (Java based servers, .Net based servers, PHP based servers and so on).
- Windows or Linux
- Any programming language

  - Bonus for any of these: Java, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby on Rails, ASP/.Net
- Open-source is optional, as well as free software.
- Being able to code some changes is mandatory, since there are a few things missing.

Also, if some known software is somewhat similar to this, I'd gladly like to know about it, does not have to perfectly fit the needs.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do product types in a pool vary from week to week or do they remain the same? Also why do clients need to know how many will be produced per week?

Comment: They do change from week to week, some weeks some products will be an amount, some other times some products will not make it to the week's production. The clients being able to see it's a bonus, not essential. It's because the week's production is fixed, and if the demand is high, some clients will gladly accept just a partial order instead of the full order. So for the clients, knowing that there's a high demand for a low supply on that week may give them some insight.

Comment: But it's from a fixed list of products, like about 10 or so.